# Swift how to resize elements depending on screen size

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I've got all my elements in the view and have added constraints to position them correctly on any device.

But when it's run on a 3.5 inch iPhone some of the bottom stuff is cut off and when it's run on a iPhone 6Plus there's a lot of extra space on the bottom.

How could I resize all the elements to look good on all devices?

This is a universal app to run on iPhone and iPad.

Comment: how to deal with 3.5 inch and 6Plus device, my answer is the constraints can be improved for better effect.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you constraint an element as width equals 300...It's very bad for some elements that should fill (or fill percent of) the screen. I suggest you make percentage constraints. For example, make equal width to view, click Edit button and set Multipiler 0.6. It looks like this in storyboard:
[image]

Comment: How would this work with text inside of a label or textview? The label bounds get large as needed but the font size doesn't.

Comment: @MoCode UILabel has a option called Autoshrink. You can set max and min font size.

Answer (score 0):

make two constraints (trailing and leading for example) and make aspect ratio for your image, maybe this will help you.